# Multinomial Naive Bayes raises error

Tags: weka, dimensionality-reduction, text-classification

1) Applying MultinomialNaivesBayes(not by any other classifier) in weka raises exception "problem evaluating classifier: Numeric attribute values must all be greater or equal to zero" ? How to fix it ?

2) Is dimensionality reduction (PCA, LSI, Random projection) is an alternative for feature selection (InformationGain, ChiSqr) or we need to apply both ? I have seen conflicting opinions about them on internet ?

Comment: I am getting the same error on MNIST dataset when applying PCA for preprocessing. I have no idea why.